# Laravel\WordPress - building an array with menu and submenu items from WP database

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am setting up [navigation menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) in WordPress, and since I am making a service layer in Laravel for the data from WordPress, I am trying to create an array with menu and submenu items with the help of the [corcel package](https://github.com/corcel/corcel):

```
    foreach ($menu->nav_items as $item) {
        $parent_id = $item->meta->_menu_item_menu_item_parent;
        $res[$parent_id][] = $item;
    }

    foreach ($res[0] as $item) {
        if (isset($res[$item->ID])) {
            foreach($res[$item->ID] as $subItem) {
                $res[$item->ID]['subitem'] = $subItem;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, out of this I would like to get json data that would like something like this:

```
'menu': [ '0' : {
             menuobject, 
             subitems: [
               {subitemObject},
               {subitemObject}
             ]
           },
           '1': {
             menuobject, 
             subitems: [
               {subitemObject},
               {subitemObject}
             ]
           }
           ...and so on
```

But, with the suggested way of doing it in the package I get big chunk of data where it is not easy to see which menu has which submenu and other data.

How can I build the array with menu and submenu items from the data I get from the WordPress database with the corcel package?

Comment: explain bit clear about your question.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170033/convert-output-of-nav-menu-items-into-a-tree-like-multidimensional-array